# Extracting and matching Keys/Values/Words etc from OCR JSON

Tags: python, json, ocr

I'm trying to match KEY_VALUE_SET info to it's real names. This is from Textract already ([JSON](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h5AG7ROQ8IFBon8u8Px-07Smq7khMW7F/view?usp=sharing)).

KEY:
KEY_VALUE_SET "Key" VALUE ID > KEY_VALUE_SET "Child" multiple CHILD ID > WORD ID > WORD TEXT

VALUE:
KEY_VALUE_SET "Key" VALUE ID > KEY_VALUE_SET "Value" CHILD ID > WORD ID > WORD TEXT

I'm just starting on this with very basic Python knowledge.

```
element = ""
childIds = ""
valueIds = ""
keyResult = ""
for item in response["Blocks"]:
    if item["BlockType"] == "KEY_VALUE_SET":
        
        if item["Confidence"]:
            keyValueSetId = "KeyValueSetID: " + item['Id']
            
            for val in item["EntityTypes"]:
                if val == "KEY":
                
                    for i in item["Relationships"]:
                        if i["Type"] == "VALUE":
                            for i in i["Ids"]:
                                count = 0
                                valueId = "ValueId" + str(count) + ": " + i
                                valueIds += valueId + " "
                                count +1
                                
                    
                        elif i["Type"] == "CHILD":
                            for i in i["Ids"]:
                                count = 0
                                childId = "ChildId" + str(count) + ": " + i
                                childIds += childId + " "
                                count +1
```

Comment: please put what is your input and expected output

Comment: my input is the JSON file in the link.
Output - is structured data for review. I need to extract Supplier Invoice number, date etc but also line items off the invoice. These are in a table.
This is a copy of the visual for the KEY_VALUES found by Textract [link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tni7KqxqyoHTlkBbedZjO38WCHxqPfjZ/view?usp=sharing)